# Android Ble clear device which are no longer advertising

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application i start a single scan which can last from some second to minutes.

In the onBatchResult i get all the devices which advertise during this period, but if one of them turn off the bluetooth i'd like to have it removed from the onBatchResult Results list.

I tryed to find a way to clear the bluetooth cache every time i on BatchResult is triggered but i wasn't able to solve the problem.

**How can i remove the device which are no longer advertising?**

Thanks fot the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `BatchScanResult` try using `onScanResult`.in `onScanResult` callback, check for the `callbackType` parameter. If it is [CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html#CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST) then get the device from the `results` and remove it from your cache.